# react native flatlist androidTV focus issue

Tags: react-native, focus, android-tv

#### Environment

- react: 16.3.1
- react-native: 0.55.3

#### Description

I've implemented a multi dimension list view on React Native with a few horizontal FlatLists . Everything displays correctly. However, when I move my focus all the way to the end of a row, the focus will automatically go to the row below when I try to go right (already at the end of the row).

Is there a solution to prevent this and make sure that focus will stop when it reaches the ends of a flatlist ?

#### Steps to Reproduce

Render a FlatList vertically with each row being another horizontal FlatList. Scroll to end of a row, try to move RIGHT and focus would go down to the next row.

#### Expected Behaviour

Expected Behaviour should be none since we're at the ends of the current row.

#### Actual Behaviour

Focus goes to the next row if at the backend of a row

#### Note

I've searched the docs and this is a specific issue to firetv/androidtv.

Same issue as [issue #20100](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20100) but the bug is "closed".

#### Sample code

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      data.push(i);

    return (
      <View>
        {[1, 2].map(() => (
          <ScrollView horizontal style={{height: 210}}>
            {data.map(i => (
              <TouchableOpacity key={i}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'grey',
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 60}}>{i}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I have discovered this is not possible for tvOS or android or firetv.  Unless I'm mistaken I am assuming there is a low number of people attempting to create connectedTv apps or if they are they have a very very simple interface

Comment: I am also having trouble with spatial navigation on Android TV. I've tried implementing my own Focusables spatial navigation system, but any type of scrolling view is still receiving focus no matter what I try. This is leading to all sorts of unexpected behavior.

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable the spatial navigation system while still allowing the TVEventHandler to send keyCodes from the remote?

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper any success?

Comment: @Maddis No, sadly. I think we are doomed.

Comment: I sincerely want Flutter to handle TV apps, but it's currently not possible. It would be a much better framework as we've already seen on iOS and Android for phone and tablets. Not possible to build to tvOS yet and Android TV, spatial navigation is the biggest hurdle.

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper
Any success? We are running into the same problem.

Comment: @reidisaki We are running into the same issue now. Did you manage to solve it eventually?

Comment: Unfortunately, we had to do our own fully baked in custom solution. overriding onKeyPress and handle focus all on our own side.

Comment: @Budaa No, I gave up when I switched projects at work. Also, I switched to Flutter for all of my personal projects which has better tooling, documentation, simpler type safety (Dart), widget composition, performance, bytecode compilation... I'm putting faith in Google that they will eventually support TV devices, but mostly I need it for touch screen devices. By the way, web developer here and the transition has been blissful.

Comment: sorry everyone never was able to solve this. we started to implement our own focus library which was never used though.

Answer (score 5):

This is not really a (proper) solution, but more of a hack, but it does the job.. I found this out by pure coincidence; if you add a `border` to the `ScrollView`, you won't have this problem.. So you can maybe play around with this a bit (e.g. an invisible border).

Comment: This is a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to handle this by setting the last item's `nextFocusRight` property to `null` or `undefined`.